# Android Studio 3.4 - layout designer "tools" missing

Tags: android-studio, layout

When designing layouts in the Designer of Android Studio 3.4 I am missing the "tools" feature.
In older versions, there was a small button that allowed to set a properts in the tools mode (only visible in designer) instead of setting it for the android name space.
So in the XML it would be written

```
tools:background="#aaa"
```

instead of

```
android:background="#aaa"
```

However, with the new version, this is gone. It only seems to show the wrench symbol when I set this manually in the XML. But the button for adding a tools-property directly seems gone.

**Any idea where the button went to?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check under **declared attributes**

Press the + sign on the right and you can see a new row has been added below where you can search tools: {see the image below}

[image: Press the + sign on the right and you can see a new row has been added below where you can search for tools: {see the image }]

[image]

Or still, you can use the old school way like the above pic.

Comment: So I still have to type it myself? The version before allowed a click directly at the property.

Comment: I think that option is still available there.

Comment: But when you remove the tools text, this form disappears. How do you get it? Only by writing it manually as shown above?